# android reset id after setID() has been used

Tags: android

I use setID() to id children of a view (e.g. when creating TableRows in TableLayout).  I can retrieve the children (rows), but sometimes I need to change the previously set ID's to new values.  When I retrieve a child and apply a new setID(newID), it does not seem to change the previously set child's ID (e.g. when inserting a new row, wish to re-index the rows following the newly inserted row).

Is that the expected behaviour?  Are ID "permanent" after first assignment?  Is there some other way to change the ID?

I appreciate I can create a "mapping variable" that tracks the updated indexing wrt to the childID's ... but is there not an object method or something that does this directly?

Answer (score 1):

use `setTag()` instead. A view's ID is not intended to change or to be used in the manner that you're using them here; a view's tag however is intended for you to use as you please.

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt response.  Started to consider using your suggestion of Tags, but in the end it was much simpler to create a "mapping" ArrayList with the keys as the row nums, and the objects as the childID's (ArrayList instead of int[] to avoid predefined size, allow direct "insertion/deletion" etc, ).  Then all manipulations on the ArrayList are trivially simple, and can access all the children as needed with getChildAt(ArrList.get(rownum)) etc ... at least for this specific situation.

Comment: @user3024046 I am trying to do something similar can you share your code so that i get some clarity. Thanks.